# Prepend models to collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm looking for an elegant way to prepend models to a collection when adding them. In the Backbone source code there is an `unshift` method to do just that, but the `add` method for adding models to a collection is too complex to simply extend. I'm building a slide show that depends on photos and tweets and should always show the newest on top, oldest last. Simplification of my problem:

Initialize app, API call returns:

```
apple, banana, lemon
```

So, apple is the newest slide. The collection is built:

```
apple, banana, lemon
```

After interval, API call checks if there are newer fruits, result:

```
orange
```

Collection appends model:

```
(apple, banana, lemon), orange
```

That's not what I want; orange is the newest fruit, and apple after that. But, in this case I could reverse my initial collection before appending and re-reverse when drawing slides. Now, things get more complex (I added parentheses to clarify):

API call checks for even more fruits:

```
pineapple, kiwi
```

Collection appends new models one by one:

```
((apple, banana, lemon), orange), pineapple, kiwi
```

So now from new to old, my collection looks like this:

```
((not so old, older, oldest), pretty new), brand new, new
```

Which makes absolutely no sense :)

Ofcourse, changing the API response could make my life easier, but that's currently not an option; also, it shouldn't really matter as the order of items in the response is new -> old which is fine by me.

I couldn't find an out of the box solution for this and I don't want to overcomplicate things by cloning part of the backbone source just to `unshift` new models. Suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: How would `unshift` not work? From the docs "Add a model at the beginning of a collection. Takes the same options as add."

Comment: Because I don't manually add a model to the collection, I use an interval to fetch json from the server and Backbone appends each object as a model to the collection. Sure I could intervene and use `unshift` but that would have complexified my code (maybe I should have pointed out that my API endpont is not a real representation of my collection, it's a sort of 'streaming' collection)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the models have some kind of date or time associated with them or indeed any other kind of ordering  (you can potentially add one manually if needed) you can sort the collection by implementing the `comparator` function in your collection. See:

http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-comparator

Comment: Thanks!! Don't know how I overlooked that in the docs. Problem solved: `this.collection.comparator = function(model) { return -model.get("time"); }`

Comment: For those who got stuck on a reverse created_at comparator not working, don't forget to parse the string before negating!

``function(model) { return -Date.parse(model.get('created_at')) }``