# Prepend new model to a collection after a fetch (without comparator)

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

So I display my collection in a classic collection view. On button  allows me to load the next item. This one works great.

The problem is that I also want to create a load previous button and currently after the fetch the new models are appened to the collection.

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13178950/prepend-models-to-collection) post but unfortunately I can't use a comparator because I can't sort my models based on their attributes, the backend does.

edit: I finally came with this workaround, not a very big fan though:

```
oldCollection = new Backbone.Collection(myCollection)

myCollection.fetch
  remove: true

myCollection.add(oldModel.toJSON())
```

Answer (score 4):

to prepend to a collection, you have to call add with optional parameter:

http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-add

```
myCollection.add(oldModel.toJSON(), {at:0})
```

Comment: yes absolutely but here myCollection get the new models after the fetch. I then append my old model to the new model.

Instead of prepending new model to my oldmodel.